# Printing only business working days

Tags: java, arrays, calendar, simpledateformat

I've been stuck on this issue for the past 4 hours trying different strategies which haven't prevailed much at all having checked countless posts on here and Google. Basically what I am trying to do is print out only the business working days within a week mon-fri. I have tried incrementing the day of the year each time the weekend days come up but of course this messes up the order of the days after. For example instead of having:

```
 Iteration: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8....

 Day: (0)Friday, (1)Saturday, (2)Sunday, (3)Monday, (4)Tuesday, (5)Wednesday, (6)Thursday, (7)Friday, (8)Saturday....etc
```

I require:

```
   Day: (0)Friday, (1)Monday, (2)Tuesday (3)Wednesday, (4)Thursday, (5)Friday, (6)Monday, (7)Tuesday, (8)Wednesday....etc
```

Here's the code:

```
public static void date(int day) {
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//version 1
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM yyyy"); //version 2

    String[] days = new String[maxDayCount];      //limits the number of days to print out(ordinarily h)
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day + 1);     //Increments from test count + 1 due to count starting at 0 (would be today). Increments the date to get from today.

    int DayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    boolean WorkingDayCheck = ((DayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY) && (DayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY));

    if(WorkingDayCheck) {
        days[day] = format.format(now.getTime());
    } else {
      //
    }
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println("-----------Day " + day + ": " + String.valueOf(days[day]));    //v2: print out each line
}//END OF METHOD: date
```

The idea is that I have an iteration elsewhere which passes the day number to this method in order for this to use that number to then print out the date. I am now back to what I was with originally before trying a load of things which at the moment with the check I am doing with the WorkingDayCheck boolean the print out is of course returning null when the weekend days come about.

Any ideas chaps?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: this probably isn't the best way... but you could put it into a while loop and check if day.equals("saturday" or "sunday") then do that add or skip it to go to the next one

Comment: That's one thing I have already tried and I did get it working to a point however the problem I had was later as since I skipped to monday for saturday and tuesday for sunday, I had duplicate week days when the iteration reached a genuine monday or tuesday so I had things like: Friday, Monday, Tuesday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... etc. I would of had to increase the date for every week day that wasn't coming from a weekend date which is rather a going on and there should be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

First, why do you define the array `days` each time you enter the method then you populate only one value in it?

Your `String[] days = new String[maxDayCount];` should be a member variable not a local variable. So initialize this array outside this method.

Also initialize another `int` that represent the last empty location in your array. (defaults to `0`)

```
public class Foo {
  int maxDayCount = 365;
  String[] days = new String[maxDayCount];
  int finalIndex = 0;

  public static void date(int day) {
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM yyyy");

    String[] days = new String[maxDayCount];      //limits the number of days to print out(ordinarily h)
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day + 1);     //Increments from test count + 1 due to count starting at 0 (would be today). Increments the date to get from today.

    int DayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    boolean WorkingDayCheck = ((DayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY) && (DayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY));

    if(WorkingDayCheck) {
        days[finalIndex++] = format.format(now.getTime());
        System.out.print("(" + (finalIndex - 1) + ")" + String.valueOf(days[finalIndex - 1]))
    } else {
      //
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    int day = 0;
    while(finalIndex != maxDaysCount) {
      date(day++);
    }
  }
}
```

Now your `days` array will be populated with working days only in their respective indices. For example in `days[0]` will be `Friday` then `days[1]` will be `Saturday` and so on since you have a pointer `finalIndex` that is independent of the value of `day` that is input to your method from the iteration.

Comment: Funnily enough I was thinking about the point of the array before since it is only being populated by one, the idea was that I'd get it working and then improved upon this where possible later.

Comment: @Mohammed Osama Having just tried the code now, it seems to just replaces where saturday and sunday was originally with friday: (0) Friday, (0)Friday, (0)Friday, (1)Monday, (2)Tuesday etc. Instead it should be replaced with the next working days being monday and tuesday like so: (0) Friday, (1)Monday, (2)Tuesday, (3)Wednesday, (4)Thursday etc. I know this is because of the `if(WorkingDayCheck)` however I am unsure what should be used in the else when these days are encountered.

Comment: Yes that is what it prints because the `System.out.print("(" + (finalIndex - 1) + ")" + String.valueOf(days[finalIndex - 1]))` is outside of the loop only for demonstration so your final Index pointer does not change on weekends which prints Friday in their place. The array was always populated correctly though `;)`. I will edit the code now.

Comment: @Mohammed Osama I understand now, thanks a lot. Having now re-ran the code its almost there as it now prints: Friday to Monday, the problem however is that the day int that is being fed in from another method is incrementing by 1 each time it is ran as the maxDayCount in this case is 20. So now it prints: (0)Friday, (1)Monday, (2)Tuesday, (3)Wednesday, (4)Thursday, (5)Friday.... up to a total of 13 times due to there being a total of 6 weekends in this period and the issue is these weekend days shouldn't be missed out and included.

Comment: You said that you require this output `(0)Friday, (1)Monday, (2)Tuesday (3)Wednesday, (4)Thursday, (5)Friday, (6)Monday, (7)Tuesday, (8)Wednesday`, how can I include weekends here, you want them in the array?

Comment: The output I mentioned is correct but it needs to take into account the day int that is being fed in like so: Day 0: (0) Friday, Day 1: (1) Monday, Day 2: (2) Tuesday, Day 3: (3) Wednesday etc. Instead of what I now have which is: Day 0: (0) Friday, Day 1: , Day 2: , Day 3: (1) Monday, Day 4: (2) Tuesday, Day 5: (3) Wednesday etc. As you see the day increment becomes out of sync due to the day incrementation covering the weekend days.

Comment: Actually it makes sense that the day should increment but now if you want to print the whole number of maximum days then you should now generate day using `for(int i = 0; i < maxDayCount; i++)` instead keep generating days until `finalIndex` is equal to `maxDayCount. This way you will get you whole array filled with weekdays only  and you will get your correct number of weekdays. If your input is 21 then you will get 21 weekdays instead of the 13 you get now.

Comment: I added a main method to demonstrate.

Comment: We're getting closer, as it now prints the correct number of dates however the problem now is that in the main method where the iteration of the day int is which is passed as a parameter into the date method, all the dates are printed at once instead of one at a time (the idea is that it processes and prints a value, then the day method is called to retrieve the date for that value and prints it, then the iteration moves onto the next value in the iteration and repeat etc.

Comment: Add your necessary logic to your main method.  I was addressing the solution to your dates problem. Also I dont quiet get what you ask for again.  Whay exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem correctly you want to do somewhat like following,

```
Working Day #1 = 0 Week + 1 Day = 1st Day
..
Working Day #5 = 0 Week + 5 Days = 5th Day
Working Day #6 = 1 Week + 1 Day = 8th Day
..
Working Day #10 = 1 Week + 5 Days = 12th Day
```

And then print the **1st,2nd,3rd** calendar day of the year.

If that is the case you can try finding the calendar day from working day like something,

```
    int div = day/5;
    int rem = day%5;
    int calendarDay = 0;
    if(day>5){
        if(rem == 0)
            calendarDay = (div-1)*7 + 5;
        else
            calendarDay = div*7 + rem;
    }else
        calendarDay = day;
```

And then find the Calendar day for that date like

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.ENGLISH);
    formatter.format("%tD", calendar);
    System.out.println(sb);
```

The code is not a solution, but I guess it points to where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Having played around with the code I have achieved what I was after now with:

```
    public static String getDate4(int day) {
       now = Calendar.getInstance();
       //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//version 1
       SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM yyyy"); //version 2

       now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day + 1);     //Increments from test count + 1 due to count starting at 0 (would be today). Increments the date to get from today.

       int DayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
       boolean WorkingDayCheck = ((DayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY) && (DayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY));

       if(WorkingDayCheck) {
            days[finalIndex++] = format.format(now.getTime());
        return "\n(" + (finalIndex - 1) + ") " + String.valueOf(days[finalIndex - 1]);
        } else {
            now.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);  //advance dates by two
            dayCount = dayCount + 2;    //Increase the day count by 2 to ensure that later dates are also incremented to avoid duplication i.e. Monday(Sat), Tuesday(Sun), Monday, Tuesday, Wed...
            days[finalIndex++] = format.format(now.getTime());
          return "\n(" + (finalIndex - 1) + ") " + String.valueOf(days[finalIndex - 1]);
       }//END OF if else
    }//END OF getDate4 method
```

I had to add and use an external dayCount (similar to the day int @Mohammed Osama used) separate from the count used in the mains methods iteration which I used previously to feed into this method and then when a weekend came up I incremented the date by 2 which is something I had experimented with before however the problem came when the weekend ended and it was back onto non weekend dates which ended up with:

```
Friday
Monday (previously Saturday)
Tuesday (previously Sunday)
Monday (weekend over, now back onto Monday) <--- Issue here and onwards
Tuesday
```

This is where the new dayCount came in which is now fed into this method simply as:

```
//Main method
//Iteration code start
getDate4(dayCount++);
//Iteration end
```

Incrementing this by 2 each time a weekend was encountered pushed the later dates to their appropriate position therefore now I am getting what I was always after being:

```
Friday
Monday (previously Saturday) <-Pushed ahead by 2 dates to Monday
Tuesday (previously Sunday)  <-Pushed ahead by 2 dates to Tuesday
Wednesday (previously Monday) <-Pushed ahead 2 dates to Wednesday due to weekends incrementing the dayCount by 2
Thursday <--- etc. etc.
```

Thanks a lot for the help folks, can move on now finally :>